# CSS layout help - Multiline address

Tags: css

I'm trying to display an address right aligned in the footer of my page like this:

```
1234 south east Main St.
    Nowhere, ID 45445
        (555) 555-5555
```

in my markup I have this:

```
<address>
   1234 south east Main St.
   Nowhere, Id 45445
   (555) 555-5555
</address>
```

How can I get this to layout properly without inserting <br /> in each line using css?

Comment: Your CSS needs More Cowbell...

Comment: Ideally it would better to mark it up with the `adr` microformat. Google 'hCard' for the spec. Also the <address> element is intended for marking up the page author's contact information/url and not addresses (as confusing as that is).

Comment: @sanchothefat - are those tags considred part of strict XHTML?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

hey try to use this use this

```
.address
{
white-space:pre;
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: This works. thanks. The only problem is I'm forced in my markup to layout my text a certain way.

Comment: @micah you aren't using a separate Stylesheet?

Comment: Yes of course. What I'm saying is that using the "white-space:pre" forces me to have my markup in a particular format in order for it to work.

Comment: @micah Keep in mind that the <address> tag is meant to be used only for displaying contact information for the given page.  You shouldn't use it for any other addresses.  see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.6  If you're not trying to display contact information for the page but still want some standard way of displaying an address then take a look at http://microformats.org/.  Specifically the hcard might be what you want.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342457/what-html-tags-are-there-for-address-information

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to add extra elements in there, either `<br>` as you suggest, or else something like:

```
   <address>
      <div class="street">1234 south east Main St.</div>
      <div class="state">Nowhere, Id 45445</div>
      <div class="telnum">(555) 555-5555</div>
   </address>
```

Answer (score -1):

First it's a good practice in this case to give an id to the address. Of course if you don't use another address again, it's not necessary. Then:

```
address#company_address
{
  white-space: pre;
  text-align: right;
}
```