# Should <br /> and <hr /> be avoided at all costs in web design?

Tags: html, css

I continuously find places where I need to use the `<br />` tag because CSS can't do what I need. Isn't the `<br />` considered part of the "design" and not part of document structure? What is the acceptable usage for it? Should the same rules also apply to the `<hr />`?

Here is an example of where I feel forced to use the `<br />` tag:

I want to display this:

`<address>1234 south east Main St. Somewhere, Id 54555</address>`

like this:

```
1234 south east main st.
Somewhere, Id 54555
```

Comment: Why are you turning this question into a duplicate of your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462585/css-layout-help-multiline-address

Comment: Gortok - Seems fine to me. His previous question asked how to accomplish a specific effect. This question is more or of a design philosophy question, and in effect asks if he should have even needed to ask the other question. They are not duplicates.

Comment: @Joshua: You missed my question, the other question addressed that he doesn't have to use BR or HR to accomplish the same thing.  It's a great question; but I don't want to see someone close it because it duplicates what the other question answers.

Comment: This question was spawned from the deeper issues that the other question brings up.

Comment: FYI, I would just like to point out that the <address> tag is meant to markup information regarding the author of a document. It's not semantically meant to markup street addresses:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_address.asp

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using <br /> or <hr />. Neither of them are deprecated tags, even in the new HTML 5 draft spec (relevant [spec info](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-hr-element)). In fact, it's hard to state correct usage of the <br /> tag better than the W3C itself:

> *The following example is correct usage of the br element:*
>
> <p>P. Sherman<br>
>     42 Wallaby Way<br>
>     Sydney</p>
>
> *br elements must not be used for separating thematic groups in a paragraph.*
>
> *The following examples are non-conforming, as they abuse the br element:*
>
> <p><a ...>34 comments.</a><br>
>     <a ...>Add a comment.<a></p>
>
> <p>Name: <input name="name"><br>
>     Address: <input name="address"></p>
>
> *Here are alternatives to the above, which are correct:*
>
> <p><a ...>34 comments.</a></p>
>     <p><a ...>Add a comment.<a></p>
>
> <p>Name: <input name="name"></p>
>     <p>Address: <input name="address"></p>

<hr /> can very well be part of the content as well, and not just a display element. Use good judgement when it comes to what is content and what is not, and you'll know when to use these elements. They're both valid, useful elements in the current W3C specs. But with great power comes great responsibility, so use them correctly.

**Edit 1:**

Another thought I had after I first hit "post" - there's been a lot of anti-<table> sentiment among web developers in recent years, and with good reason. People were abusing the <table> tag, using it for site layout and formatting. That's not what it's for, so you shouldn't use it that way. But does that mean you should **never** use the <table> tag? What if you actually have an honest-to-goodness table in your code, for example, if you were writing a science article and you wanted to include [the periodic table of the elements](http://www.webelements.com/)? In that case, the use of <table> is totally justified, it becomes semantic markup instead of formatting. It's the same situation with <br />. When it's part of your content (ie, text that should break at those points in order to be correct English), use it! When you're just doing it for formatting reasons, it's best to try another way.

Comment: It's also worth quoting the `<hr>` HTML5 spec, which explains its semantic meaning neatly: **"The hr element represents a paragraph-level thematic break, e.g. a scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a section of a reference book."**

Comment: @Joshua - forgive me posting in such an old thread, but I can see on your profile that you were last seen a few hours ago, so you're apparently still an active SO member :). Well, you see, I can't spot a difference between the "correct" usage and the "non-conforming" examples o_O In both cases there is a `<br>` tag inside a `<p>` tag. So where is the difference? I mean I can see the `<a>` and `<input>` tags, but I don't think this is it.

Comment: Hi @konrad_firm. You're right that from a technical standpoint, the two uses might look the same. The difference is in semantic meaning. In the case of a postal address, the line break is part of the data. It would always have a line break, even if it were written in Notepad, or on a tiny screen. In the "incorrect" usage, the line break is being used for presentation. What if you wanted to format the two links differently on a tiny screen, or for a screen reader, or a different country? The <br> can't be changed in CSS, so it should be avoided for presentation purposes. Make sense?

Comment: @Joshua - very BIG thank you, yes, now it makes perfect sense. Especially the last two sentences. Finally, after so many years I understand this :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 15):

Just so long as you don't use <br/> to form paragraphs, you're probably alright in my book ;) I hate seeing:

```
<p>
  ...lengthy first paragraph...
  <br/>
  <br/>
  ...lengthy second paragraph...
  <br/>
  <br/>
  ...lengthy third paragraph...
</p>
```

As for an address, I would do it like this:

```
<address class="address">
  <span class="street">1100 N. Wullabee Lane</span><br/>
  <span class="city">Pensacola</span>, <span class="state">Florida</span> 
  <span class="zip">32503</span>
</address>
```

But that's likely because I love jQuery and would like access to any of those parts at any given moment :)

Comment: why not simply use an <address> tag?
<address>1100 N. Wullabee Lane<br/>
Pensacola, FL<br/>
32503</address>

Comment: You're right. I've never used that tag before, but it does appear to be the most proper element to use. Thanks.

Comment: This is getting pretty tangential, but you might want to look at the hcard microformat. It lets the (few) people that have browser support automatically import addresses into their address book, do map lookups, etc.

Comment: Why place a br after street, instead of setting street to `display: block`? Is it because `BR` is inline, and thus can cause a line break in an inline element, where as containing a block level in an inline element is improper?

Comment: @crush You could make `.street` block. The `address` element is also `block` by default. I suspect, at the time, the decision was arbitrary to use the `<br>` element.

Comment: @JonathanSampson So it is. I didn't even notice you were using `<address>`. I think I assumed it was nested in `<p>` or something. *Needs more sleep*

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It's just what you like and what you hate, without any reasoning (apart from personal taste reasoning). -- edit: nevermind, it's a 6 1/2 years old answer. gosh, how time goes by.

Answer (score 7):

`<hr />` and `<br />`, much like everything else, can be abused to do design when they shouldn't be.  `<hr />` is meant to be used to visually divide sections of text, but in a localized sense.  `<br />` is meant to do the same thing, but without the horizontal line.

It would be a design flaw to use `<hr />` across a site as a design, but in this post, for instance, it would be correct to use both `<br />` and `<hr />`, since this section of text would still have to be a section of text, even if the site layout changed.

Answer (score 5):

I believe *absolutely avoiding* usage of a commonly accepted solution (even it is outdated) is the same thing as designing a table with `<div>` tags instead of `<table>` tags, just so you can use `<div>`.

When designing your website, you probably won't *require* the use of `<br />` tags, but I can still imagine them being useful where user input is needed, for example.

I don't see anything *wrong* with using `<br />` but have not come across many situation where I *required* using them. In most cases, there probably are more elegant (and prettier) solutions than using `<br />` tags if this is what you need for vertically seperating content.

Answer (score 4):

`<hr/>` and `<br/>` are presentational elements that have no semantic value to the document, so from a purist perspective yes, they ought to be avoided.

Think about HTML not as a presentational tool but rather as a document that needs to be self-describing.  `<hr/>` and `<br/>` add no semantic value - rather they represent a very specific presentation in the browser.

That all being said, be pragmatic in your approach.  Try to avoid them at all cost but if you find yourself coding up the walls and across the ceiling to avoid them then its better to just go ahead and use them.  Semantics are important but fringe cases like this are not where they matter the most.

Comment: both br and hr do have semantic purpose for separating content. If you deal with content, then a line break or horizontal rule are justified elements, but they have very little to no use in design and layout of a site.

Comment: HR absolutely has semantic value. It's much harder to make the argument that `BR` has any semantic meaning outside of the context of presentation. However, in bodies of text nodes, it can have semantic meaning. I abide by the rule: use it between text nodes, not elements. If it is being used between two elements, then it is being used for presentation. That's not to say that `BR` should be used for breaking paragraphs. In today's HTML, `BR` has almost no real usage that isn't solved by a more explicit element.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Why?  They're useful constructs.

---

Adding this addendum (with accompanying HR), in case my brief answer is construed as lacking appropriate consideration. ;)

It can be, and often is, an incredible waste of time -- time someone else is usually paying for -- trying to come up with cross-browser CSS-limited solutions to UI problems that BR and HR tags, and their likes, can solve in two seconds flat.  Why some UI folks waste so much time trying to come up with "pure" ways of getting around using tried-and-true HTML constructs like line breaks and horizontal rules is a complete mystery to me; both tags, among many others, are totally legitimate and are indeed there for you to use.  "Pure," in that sense, is nonsense.

One designer I worked with simply could not bring himself to do it; he'd waste hours, sometimes days, trying to "code" around it, and still come up with something that didn't work in Opera.  I found that totally baffling.  Dude, add BR, done.  Totally legal, works like a charm, and everyone's happy.

I'm all for abstracting presentation, don't get me wrong; we're all out do to the best work we can.  But be sensible.  If you've spent five hours trying to figure out some way to achieve, in script, something that BR gives you right now, and the gods won't rain fire down on you for doing it, then do it, and move on.  Chances are if it's that problematic, there might be something wrong with your solution, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I put in a `<hr style="display:none">` between sections. For example, between columns in a multi-column layout. In browsers with no support for CSS the separation will still be clear.

Comment: oohh, I'm not sure about this one, it's an interesting idea though. Do you know of anywhere that discusses this idea?

Comment: I don't know any places that discuss this, but I do this as well (minus the inline style), and for the same reason: separating distinct sections for those without CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I have always used `<br/>` as a carriage return (and hence as part of content, really). Not sure if that is the right way of going about it, but its served me well.

`<hr/>` on the other hand...

Comment: exactly what a line break is. Horizontal rule also has it's place in content, but not so commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not say *at all costs* but if you want to be purist, these tags have nothing to do with structure and everything to layout but HTML is supposed to separate content from presentation.  `<hr />` can be done through CSS and `<br/>` through proper use of otehr tags like `<p>`.

If you do not want to be a purist, use them :)

Comment: HTML does provide layout in the semantic meaning, but not in style. A paragraph, table, or list will produce layout just like an HR and BR tag, it's just that you're supposed to use them for what they are and don't use a hr because it works to provide a pretty horizontal line above a title.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should seldom need the BR tag in your templates. But at times it can be called for in the content, user generated and system generated. Like if you want to keep a piece of text in the paragraph but need a newline before it.

What are the occasions where you feel you are forced to use BR tags?

Answer (score 1):

`<br>` is the HTML way of expressing a line break, as there is no other way of doing it.

Physical line breaks in the source code are rightfully ignored (more correctly: treated as a single white space), so you need a markup way to express them.

Not every line break is the beginning of a new paragraph, and packing text into `<div>`s (for example) just to avoid `<br>`s seems overly paranoid to me. Why do they bother you?

Comment: You are correct to say that <br/> is the only way to express a line break in HTML but this is something that can be better expressed in CSS where it belongs.

Comment: "can be better expressed": How?

Comment: Apart from that: "where it belongs" - I think *that* assumption is wrong. Line breaks are not part of the presentation. They are part of the data. Call the <br> tag the necessary compromise, if you like.

Comment: I can see what you mean but proper layout with CSS negates the need for presentational elements like <br/> and if you really need a line break you can clear the left side of your element.

Comment: Let's agree on the fact that a line break is meant to be a line break. I don't think it should be used as a spacer, which indeed would be "presentational use". Ripping consecutive text apart, wrapping both parts in <span>'s just so you can "clear:left" on one of them is the wrong way to do it, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

BR is fine, since a hard line-break could be part of the content, for example in code blocks (even though you'd probably use the PRE-element for that) or lyrics.

HR on the other hand is purely presentational: a horizontal rule, a horizontal line. Use border-top/bottom for neighbouring elements instead.

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel that, in the interest of true separation of content and style, both `<br />` and `<hr />` should be avoided.

As far as doing away with `<br />` tags in my own markup, I use `<div>` in conjunction with the css `margin` property to handle anything that needs a line break, and a `<span>` for anything that would be inline, but of a different "content class" (obviously distinguishing them with the `class` attribute).

To replace an `<hr />` tag with css, I simply create a `<div>` with the `border-top-style` css property set to `solid` and the other three sides set to `none`. The `margin` and the `padding` properties of said `<div>` then handle the actual placement/positioning of the horizontal line.

Like I said, I'm no expert, my web design experience is mostly a side effect of my work with JSP pages (I am a Java programmer), but I came upon this question during some research and wanted to put my two cents in...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<br>` but don't use `<hr>`.

`<BR>` — LINE BREAK
— This is display information. Still in
   common use, but use with restraint.

`<HR>` — HORIZONTAL RULE
— Display info with no semantic value –
   never use it. “Horizontal”, by definition, is a visual attribute.

Source: [Proper Use Guide for HTML Tags](http://webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/list-of-html-tags-with-semantic-usage/)

Comment: Why "with restraint" and "never"? Any reasons?

Comment: HTML is for describing web page structure.  CSS is for describing presentation.  Line break is structural but horizontal rule includes presentation information.  For example, if we wanted to render the HTML content rotated 90 degrees onto it's side, line break would still make sense but not the "horizontal" rule.

Answer (score 0):

That's bad usage if you're going Strict.

`<br/>` and `<hr/>` are not part of the content. For instance the `<hr/>` is commonly used to separate blocks of text. But isn't possible to that with border-bottom? And `<br/>` is seen in many cases as a way to limit text to a certain form, which couldn't be accomplished with css?

Of course you aren't going Strict don't worry to much.

Answer (score 0):

HR has some hacky uses right now in preventing mobile browsers' font inflation algorithms from kicking in.

Also if you have lots of small content separated by HRs, the Googlebot will currently see it as 'N separate entries', which might be useful to you.

BRs should really only be used as a line break within a paragraph, which is a pretty rare typographical usage (except perhaps within a table cell), and I'm not aware of any hacky reason to use them.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an excerpt from a course that helps you learn html.

```
<form>
    <p>Choose your pizza toppings:</p>
    <label for="cheese">Extra cheese</label>
    <input id="cheese" name="topping" type="checkbox" value="cheese">
    <br>
    <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
    <input id="pepperoni" name="topping" type="checkbox" value="pepperoni">
    <br>
    <label for="anchovy">Anchovy</label>
    <input id="anchovy" name="topping" type="checkbox" value="anchovy">
```