# Should we give id's to <hr> <br> etc?

Tags: html, css

Just had a discussion on some html concepts and the question arises should we give id's to hr and br tags. Both do not contain/handle the content in any way and both have fixed functionality. So invoking the DOM on basis of id's is a good coding practice or not?

Take scenario suppose I want to apply css to a hr tag. One option is giving hr an id/class like

```
<hr id="hrIdName"></hr>
```

and use css like

```
#hrIdName
{
}
```

Other is enclose hr in div and then use selector to implement the css

```
<div id="hrIdName">
    <hr>
</div>
```

and use CSS like

```
#hrIdName hr
{
}
```

Out of two which is a better approach and meets good coding practice?

Comment: *sidenote:* avoid using `<hr>` in HTML5. Use DIV with CSS for styling

Comment: @Raptor umm... an `<hr>` is perfectly valid in HTML5, and has semantic meaning that some random `<div>` does not necessarily. There is no reason to avoid using them in HTML5.

Comment: Incorrect. HTML5 specification suggests that layout-oriented tags such as `<b>`, `<hr>`, `<i>` should be replaced with corresponding CSS.

Comment: `<hr>` means different thing now. See: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/hr.html

Comment: @Raptor `hr` is meant to be used as a separator

Comment: Can you please tell why I should not use hr? What's the problem in using it?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do either. I have been working a lot recently with jQuery Mobile and the interesting thing about that is they assign classes based on the CSS function you want.

So for example, if you wanted a HR to have margin and padding, you could use:

```
<hr class="margin-padding">
```

It would be better this way because you could re-use your classes on the same page (as you would likely want to with a hr). Also you cant repeat id's.

EDIT

Or as peopel have aid on your comments, dont use them at all because div and span elements should be used.

Comment: Can you please tell why I should not use hr? What's the problem in using it?

Comment: I don't think they are bad to use, I just personally wouldn't because you get much more flexibility when using div and span. It probably a case of preference IMO. as saiud here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462619/should-br-and-hr-be-avoided-at-all-costs-in-web-design its not bad to use them