# Trouble formatting and displaying <hr>

Tags: html, css, rules

I'm still pretty new to coding so bear with me...I have read that different browsers display horizontal rules differently. I can't seem to get it right in Firefox or Chrome (only two I've checked so far). Here is what my hr's look like in Firefox:

http://postimg.org/image/g2vn1cm3b/

The highest rule is where it needs to be. The last two columns have the wonky rules.

And here it is in Chrome:

http://postimg.org/image/wl98cvi5p/

Second and third columns are fine, first one is messed up.

Since my site is not live anywhere, I'm going to include my HTML and CSS here.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

html {
 background-color:#96d5cd;
}


#container {
 width:980px;
 border:1px solid #1f5c54;
 background-color:white;
 margin:2em auto;
}

hr {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
display:block;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#footer {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-family:amaranth, trebuchet, verdana, sans-serif;
margin-left:14em;
}

#footer li {
display:inline;
}

#main {
position:relative;
background-color:#fec161;
height:700px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}

#main #content {
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
height:400px;
text-align:justify;
}

#nav {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: patua-one;
 margin-top: 40px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
background-color:#fec161;
width:920px;
height:40px;
margin-left:10px;
} 

#nav li{
display:inline;

}

#nav li {
margin-left:0px;
}

#social {
float:right;
}

#social li {
margin-right:3.5px;
}

#social li{
display:inline;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-style: normal;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff;
}

#feature {
padding-left:10px;
overflow:hidden;
width:960px;
}


#footer {
 font-family:amaranth;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-top:0px;
}

#header {
 font-family:patua-one;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-top:0px;
 font-size:24px;
}

#header img {
 float:left;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top:10px;
}

#column1 {
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:30px;
text-align:justify;
}

#column2 h2{
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-left:90px;
}

#column2 {
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-right:0px;
text-align:justify;
margin-left:20px;
}


#column3 {
float:right;
width:275px;
margin-right:10px;
text-align:justify;
}

#column3 h2 {
 float:left;
 width:275px;
 margin-left:220px;
}

h2 {
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 100%;
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One);
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size:24px;
}

#columns {
 margin-top:20px;
}

h3 {
font-family:amaranth;
}

div span.welcome {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WELCOME :: Katie J Hunter :: Graphic Designer</title>

<link ref="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/images/favicon.ico" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/patua-one:n4:default;amaranth:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

 <div id="header">
    <img src="images/KatieHunterLogo.png" alt="Katie Hunter Graphic Designer Logo" /><br />
    
    <br />
    
    <ul id="social">
     <p><li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Katie-Hunter-Graphic-Designer/1532575640337137" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/kinetickatie" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/katiejohunter" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_linkedin.png" alt="Linked In" /></a></li>
    </p></ul>
    
    <ul id="nav"><p>
    <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li> :: 
    <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">About</a></li> :: 
    <li><a href="services.html" target="_blank">Services</a></li> :: 
    <li><a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Portfolio</a> :: 
    <li><a href="blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a></li> :: 
    <li><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
    </p></ul>
 </div><!-- end header -->
    
    <div id="feature">
    
     <span class="accentbar"><img src="images/FeatureBanner.jpg" alt="banner" class="banner" /></span><br>
    
    </div><!-- end feature -->
    
    <div id="main">
     <div id="content">
        <h1><span class="welcome">Welcome!</span></h1>
        <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
        
        <h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odi o nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odio nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odio nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.</h3>
     </div><!-- end content -->
          <div id="columns">
            <div id="column1">
    <h2>Services</h2><br />
    <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
 <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column1 -->

    <div id="column2">
     <h2>Clients</h2><br />
     <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
      <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column2 -->

    <div id="column3">
     <h2>Blog</h2><br />
     <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
     <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column3 -->
     </div><!-- end columns -->
    </div><!-- end main -->
    
     <div id="footer">
        <span><p>© copyright 2015 katie j hunter • all rights reserved</p></span><br />
        <ul id="nav2">
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/about.html" target="_blank">About</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/services.html" target="_blank">Services</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/portfolio.html" target="_blank">Portfolio</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a></li> |
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
       </div><!-- end footer -->

</div><!-- end container -->



</body>
</html>
```

What have I done wrong? Please be kind, I'm still very new at this and have been following a video tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: There is a <br> after Services, remove that for the first column issue. Remove the <br> tags under each titles and give hr a `clear:both` in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleared float for the `hr` and removed the `<br/>`

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

html {
 background-color:#96d5cd;
}


#container {
 width:980px;
 border:1px solid #1f5c54;
 background-color:white;
 margin:2em auto;
}

hr {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
display:block;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#footer {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-family:amaranth, trebuchet, verdana, sans-serif;
margin-left:14em;
}

#footer li {
display:inline;
}

#main {
position:relative;
background-color:#fec161;
height:700px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}

#main #content {
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
height:400px;
text-align:justify;
}

#nav {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: patua-one;
 margin-top: 40px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
background-color:#fec161;
width:920px;
height:40px;
margin-left:10px;
} 

#nav li{
display:inline;

}

#nav li {
margin-left:0px;
}

#social {
float:right;
}

#social li {
margin-right:3.5px;
}

#social li{
display:inline;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-style: normal;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff;
}

#feature {
padding-left:10px;
overflow:hidden;
width:960px;
}


#footer {
 font-family:amaranth;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-top:0px;
}

#header {
 font-family:patua-one;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-top:0px;
 font-size:24px;
}

#header img {
 float:left;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
padding-top:10px;
}

#column1 {
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:30px;
text-align:justify;
}

#column2 h2{
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-left:90px;
}

#column2 {
float:left;
width:275px;
margin-right:0px;
text-align:justify;
margin-left:20px;
}


#column3 {
float:right;
width:275px;
margin-right:10px;
text-align:justify;
}

#column3 h2 {
 float:left;
 width:275px;
 margin-left:220px;
}

h2 {
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 100%;
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One);
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size:24px;
}

#columns {
 margin-top:20px;
}

h3 {
font-family:amaranth;
}

div span.welcome {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: patua-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
hr {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WELCOME :: Katie J Hunter :: Graphic Designer</title>

<link ref="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/images/favicon.ico" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/patua-one:n4:default;amaranth:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

 <div id="header">
    <img src="images/KatieHunterLogo.png" alt="Katie Hunter Graphic Designer Logo" /><br />
    
    <br />
    
    <ul id="social">
     <p><li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Katie-Hunter-Graphic-Designer/1532575640337137" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/kinetickatie" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/katiejohunter" target="_blank"><img src="images/socialmedia_linkedin.png" alt="Linked In" /></a></li>
    </p></ul>
    
    <ul id="nav"><p>
    <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li> :: 
    <li><a href="about.html" target="_blank">About</a></li> :: 
    <li><a href="services.html" target="_blank">Services</a></li> :: 
    <li><a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Portfolio</a> :: 
    <li><a href="blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a></li> :: 
    <li><a href="contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
    </p></ul>
 </div><!-- end header -->
    
    <div id="feature">
    
     <span class="accentbar"><img src="images/FeatureBanner.jpg" alt="banner" class="banner" /></span><br>
    
    </div><!-- end feature -->
    
    <div id="main">
     <div id="content">
        <h1><span class="welcome">Welcome!</span></h1>
        <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
        
        <h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odi o nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odio nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sapien velit, dictum vel semper id, vestibulum eu nisi. Phasellus ac ornare sapien. Praesent eget libero mollis ipsum eleifend lacinia non ut ligula. Sed quis sem at est laoreet aliquet. Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim. Etiam odio nibh, bibendum vel eros malesuada, elementum blandit quam. Integer aliquet finibus felis et eleifend.</h3>
     </div><!-- end content -->
          <div id="columns">
            <div id="column1">
    <h2>Services</h2>
    <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
 <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column1 -->

    <div id="column2">
     <h2>Clients</h2>
     <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
      <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column2 -->

    <div id="column3">
     <h2>Blog</h2>
     <hr style="height:1px; width:100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:black;" />
     <h3>Donec ornare, ante ut fermentum ullamcorper, enim purus vehicula sem, non feugiat dolor nulla sed enim.</h3>
    </div><!-- end column3 -->
     </div><!-- end columns -->
    </div><!-- end main -->
    
     <div id="footer">
        <span><p>© copyright 2015 katie j hunter • all rights reserved</p></span><br />
        <ul id="nav2">
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/about.html" target="_blank">About</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/services.html" target="_blank">Services</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/portfolio.html" target="_blank">Portfolio</a></li> | 
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/blog.html" target="_blank">Blog</a></li> |
      <li><a href="file:///MacHD/Users/Katie/Desktop/MyNewPortfolio/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
       </div><!-- end footer -->

</div><!-- end container -->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @stealthkitty Cool. Nothing wrong in using br tags but better to avoid using  between two tags. You can read more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462619/should-br-and-hr-be-avoided-at-all-costs-in-web-design). Also you can accept this answer by ticking it if you are satisfied with this answer :)