# What HTML tags are there for address information?

Tags: html, xhtml

What address related tags are there for address and formatting and marking my address information in my webpages? I'm looking for XHTML or HTML5 compliant tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the semantic [`<address>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_address.asp). You may also want to take a look at the [hCard microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-examples).

Comment: That's it? For every part of the address? phone,  street address, zip code, city?

Comment: What would the address tag -not- do?  What exactly are you looking for it to do for every part of the address?

Comment: @charliegriefer - I was looking for the `<a tel>` tag.

Comment: @Moshe: You may also want to take a look at the hCard microformat. I've updated my answer to include a link to some examples.

Comment: The address tag is not for address information! It's meaning is basically: "information about the author of the content" (for your average HTML4 and bellow, that would be "the page") See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.6 The suggestion to use hCard microformat is correct however.

Answer (score 2):

`<address>` from W3C:

> The address element provides contact information for a document or
>   part of a document. Information provided by address may include the
>   names of the document’s maintainers, links to the maintainers’ Web
>   pages, e-mail addresses for feedback, postal addresses, phone numbers,
>   and so on. The address element is not appropriate for all postal and
>   e-mail addresses; it should be reserved for providing such information
>   about the contact people for the document. W3C HTML5 specification

Use `<address>` for addresses that are in fact the relevant contact information for a document or section of a document. Do not use it to represent arbitrary addresses.

For more detailed Address information it is recommended to use Microdata. Search Engines recognize Microformats, Microdata and RDFa, [but Microdata is recommended.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=1088472&ctx=topic)

Here is the [Microdata Postal Address page with examples.](http://www.schema.org/PostalAddress)You will be able to specify `streetAddress`, `postalCode`, `telephone` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<address>` tag. Go to following link for details.
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-address-element.html#the-address-element

Answer (score 0):

vcard in Microformats - http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-examples

vcard in Microdata - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#vcard

vcard in RDFa - http://www.w3.org/TR/vcard-rdf/#Exa